# Запятые в предложении, сомнения

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

> Через несколько лет(,)встреча с Татьяной, ставшей за время отсутствия
> Евгения женой генерала, открывает перед читателями образ главного
> героя с другой стороны.

Comment: Да ни за что. (((

Answer (score 0):

1. Если не учитывать **стилистику** предложения, то можно дать такой ответ: запятая **не ставится**.

***Через несколько лет**, / встреча с Татьяной, // ставшей за время отсутствия Евгения женой генерала,// открывает перед читателями образ главного героя с другой стороны.*

А почему автор **хочет ее поставить?** Слышит он там **произносительную** (очень короткую) паузу. Распространенное предложение делится на фонетические отрезки для удобства произношения. В даном случае выделено временное обстоятельство (детерминант) ***через несколько лет***, относящееся ко всему предложению. Произносительные паузы не обозначаются запятой, в отличие от пауз **грамматических** (подчеркнутых и обусловленных грамматикой).

Обособление таких обстоятельств **факультативно** и зависит от структуры предложения. И вот в данном предложении обособление не нужно. Иначе говоря, **актуализация**  (выделение голосом) этого обстоятельства не требуется, **нет для этого причин**.  Постановка **ЛИШНИХ ЗАПЯТЫХ** – вот в чем видится проблема.

2. Если учитывать **стилистику** предложения, то здесь требуется **редактирование** с учетом контекста.

**Что редактировать?**  (1) Желательно **структуру** первой части, где как раз  и находится спорная запятая. (2) лексическое наполнение **причастного**  оборота: три существительных с беспредложным управлением подряд. Сложно читается и понимается.

**Сравним:** "***И вот теперь** / встреча с Татьяной, ставшей...".* Здесь тоже обстоятельство в начале предложения, но слова и сочетания гармонично сочетаются, а не "отталкиваются" друг от друга, так что произносить их приходится **с заметной паузой**. Но этой паузы по грамматике быть не должно.